# 3 minute+ boot times on Ryzen build, seems to be something to do with a very slow pre session init according to performance analyzer

Tags: windows-10, boot, performance

I've had seriously longer than normal boot up times on my PC for some time now and i'm now looking in to it as i've just built 2 PC's for friends with similar specs and their PC's boot like normal and are at the desktop within 30 seconds whereas mine's taking upwards of 3 minutes from turn on to desktop, i've tried removing certain programs as well as unused ones, turned off loads of things in Autoruns to see if it's something there but nothing! So, in the end I created a trace file using Microsoft performance analyzer and have only managed to get as far as knowing it's the pre session init stage that's taking around 205 seconds to run through when booting the PC but I can't get any further down than that for some reason to dig down to find the culprit so I was wondering if there's any kind soul out there that wouldn't mind taking a quick peek at it for me and see if they can narrow down what the problem is please? I've uploaded the file to Mediafire but if you need it uploaded elsewhere then just let me know, it is also compressed down to 701Mb from 7Gb.

Thankyou.

[Trace file .etl](http://www.mediafire.com/file/md8tckiv0g16577/UNKNOWN.09-13-2020.02-26-20.Boot_1.rar/file)

EDIT:- It appears it's my newest Seagate 6Tb HDD 'cos when I disconnect it my boot is then 20 seconds. I have 3 HDD's total and the other 2 don't have the slow boot issue and 1 of those is also a Seagate drive (both shucked from USB enclosures) just a 5Tb instead of a 6. I've made sure the SSD is set to boot 1st and also be the only drive in the boot menu, I also disables the HDD's from booting but that made no difference and the boot time is still long. The Seagate drive in question id the Seagate ST6000DM003 so if anyone has any ideas to try and turn off even just that 1 drive until Windows is booted i'd give them a try as I really don't want to swap out the 6Tb drive as it's perfect otherwise for it's intended purpose and shows 100% in HDD sentinel.

Answer (score 0):

I was guided to my answer via email, the issue ended up being the VSS. The VSS had an old restore point which wasn't there anymore for that specific drive which was causing it to kind of freeze up while searching before moving on with the boot process and removing them resolved the problem as i'm now back to 20 second boot times! Simply all I had to do was delete the restore points using the following -

Open a command prompt using admin privileges;

Run the following command: vssadmin delete shadows /for=G: /oldest

After the command complete, run: vssadmin list shadows to confirm that the

snapshot has been removed from the G: volume.

If not run this command: vssadmin delete shadows /for=G: /all